# Avoid multipart/form-data for file transfert

Tags: javascript, file, upload, extjs, multipartform-data

I wrote a light http server in C which can handle simple requests. So I totally control the server side and its future evolution.

Now on my Web Application written in Javascript/ExtJS, I need to upload a file on my server.
Am I forced to use multipart/form-data to upload a file? 
Is it bad to directly send the file binary contained in a POST request?
I'm afraid that write a parser for multipart/form-data protocol takes me time for nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will ignore your file input fields if you don't set type of the form to `multipart/form-data` so I guess you will have to do that.